# reshape data frame with multiple columns but same column names

Tags: pandas, csv, stack, pivot-table, reshape

hello i have a dataframe with 1 "unique id" as an index but with same 3 questions with different data in one long row for that unique_id. I've researched stack, melt, pivot table.  trying to reshape data below with

"Given" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKzCI.png)

Final Product:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rTqp.png)

Result from provided code:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOuCE.png)

Recent code input:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aim93.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.set_index(['Unique_ID'])
samples_per_id = len(df.columns) // 3
chunks = map(lambda k: df.iloc[:, k:k+3], range(0, samples_per_id, 3))
result = pd.concat(chunks, axis=0)
```

And eventually, `result = result.sort_index()`

Comment: thanks, seemed to work but kind of jumbled the data from one row into several rows some data is missing, I posted result I got up in the question. Really appreciate it:

Comment: did you change "3" in my code to you specific needs?

Comment: anyway, it's really ugly but `df.groupby('Unique_ID').fillna(method='ffill').drop_duplicates('Unique_ID')` after the code I provided would get the job done.

Comment: thanks again, I've been working on this issue for like 3 weeks now so appreciate your input.  I posted my code I'm using in my question again, I'm fairly new to reshaping dataframes and python/pandas so can you double check I'm using my variables correct? getting an error with your last 'groupby ' code line -- "KeyError: Index(['Unique_ID'], dtype='object')"

Comment: `df.groupby('Unique_ID', as_index=False).fillna(method='ffill').drop_duplicates('Unique_ID')`should work better :)

Comment: Hey, curious I've been playing around with your code and a bit confused how it works but if my data frame is 10 columns total what numbers in your code do i need to change for it  to align properly ?

Comment: Basically the idea is that you have multiple samples for each row. So you need to divide your row into bits that are representative of one sample. From what you provided as input, I understood that you have ['Unique ID', 'A(1)', 'B(1)', 'C(1)', 'A(2)', 'B(2)', 'C(2'), ..., 'C(n)'] as columns. So you set the key ('Unique ID') as your index to identify the rows and then you split your dataframe as df[['A(1)', 'B(1)', 'C(1)']], df[['A(2)', 'B(2)', 'C(2)']], etc... then you glue the bits vertically to have all your samples aligned. The only number that may be changed is 3 which stands for A, B, C.